# Is this a characterization of Uniformly Convex spaces?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $E$ be a Banach space and let $\phi\colon [0,1]\rightarrow E$ be a continuous path such that $\phi(0)=0$ and $\phi(1)=a$ with $a\neq 0$. Suppose that $\phi$ is piecewise linear, *i.e.*, there exist $$t_0=0<t_1<\ldots<t_{n-1},t_n=1$$ such that $\phi$ is linear on every interval $[t_{i+1},t_i]$.

Define the length of $\phi$ by $$l(\phi)=\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\|\phi(t_{i+1})-\phi(t_i)\|.$$ Suppose that $E$ is uniformly convex. Is it true that the only path linear by parts joining $0$ and $a$ with length $l(\phi)=\|a\|$ is the path $\phi(t)=at$ ? Is the converse true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a normed space are equivalent:

i) the only geodesic between any pair of two points is the affine segment.

ii) the space is strictly convex.

See Prop. 7.2.1 on p.180 in [Metric Spaces, Convexity and Nonpositive Curvature](http://books.google.com/books?id=JrwzXZB0YrIC&pg=PA180) by A. Papadopoulos for this equivalence and quite a few others.

On the other hand, [Day showed](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183503576) that there are (reflexive) strictly convex spaces which are not even isomorphic to a uniformly convex space, so the converse you ask about is not true (unless the space is finite-dimensional).